# MVC model binding not working for 12hr Timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

i have a TimeSpan? property in my model and i have a view that is attempting to get a 12hr time value via bootstrap datetimepicker with a format of 'hh:mm a'.

When i assign a 12hr time through the view, my model keeps rejecting the value and i can see that the value assigned to the property is always null.  (YET this works fine when i was using 24hr time). Also, if i don't enter a time, and leave the prompt empty the post of the view works.

Here is my view

```
       <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Time", new { @class = "control-label col-form-label text-right" })
            <div class="">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TheTime, new {@class = "form-control form-control-sm", dataUserDefined = "true", placeholder = "Time"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TheTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

The Time in the model is simply

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Time.")]
    public TimeSpan? TheTime {get; set;}
```

Now the reg expression does it's thing on the view, and verifies that whats entered is a 12hr format.   The validation seems to pass.. cause i don't get a Invalid time message.  The postback shows the ModelBinder.IsValid is false.

I've tried breaking down the auto-property to have a backing field so as to inspect the 'value' coming in to the set.  and i see that in the set the value is always null.  So the mvc model binder just doesn't know what to do with the time in a 12hr format.

Any ideas?  Thanks much.

Does timespan binding for 12 hr formatting need a Custom Model Binder?

[UPDATE]: 
so i tried a custom model binder. BUT the same problem Exists!!

I see the correct value coming in when i check ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request["TheTime"];

i convert it into a timespan using (note TheVModel is my viewmodel):

**CUSTOM MODEL BINDER**

```
public class TimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
   public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
      var model = (TheVModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
      var the12HrTime = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["TheTime"];

      DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(the12HrTime, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      TimeSpan? ts = t.TimeOfDay;

      model.TheTime = ts;
      return model;
    } 
 }
```

I can SEE that the HttpContext.Request["TheTime"] has the 12hr time.
I can see that the timespan ts is created correctly and TheTime is correctly set in the property... but i think since the mvc binder already tried to do it's thing it's too late to do anything.

Comment: Is it really this complicated to deal with Time on a View... gez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution i went with... the MVC ModelBinder just doesn't like dealing with a TimeSpan? field, it would always just return a model state of INVALID. So since i don't know how to tell the mvc model binder to SKIP binding that field, i went the approach of not letting the model binder bind to that field.

So i added an additional STRING property to my ViewModel and had the VIEW use that Property.  Then using the CUSTOM MODEL Binder below (similar but slight change to the one previous), i move the STRING time value into the REAL TimeSpan? property of my Model.

So:

**CUSTOM BINDER**

```
public class TimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
        {
            public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {    
                var model = (ReceiptClassifyDetailViewModel)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
                var the12HrTime = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["TempTimeOnVM"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(the12HrTime))
                {
                    DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(the12HrTime, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    TimeSpan? ts = t.TimeOfDay;
                    model.TheTime = ts;
                }

                return model;
            }
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("The Time", new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4  control-label col-form-label text-right" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TempTimeOnVM, new {@class = "form-control timemask form-control-sm", dataUserDefined = "true", placeholder = "Time"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TempTimeOnVM, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Additional property to support the original TimeSpan? property.**

```
public string TempTimeOnVM { get; set; }
```